# I am using Web View inside a fragment. how to go back in web view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, webview, android-webview

this is the web view fragment

public class Home extends Fragment {

```
public Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    WebView webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com"); 
    return v;

}
```

}

I created web view inside other fragment not in main activity and when I press back button the app will close. so how to go back only inside web view (not through fragments)? please give me a solution.

here is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
}

Home homeFragment = new Home();
Live_And_Event_Schedule live_and_event_scheduleFragment = new Live_And_Event_Schedule();
Photos photosFragment = new Photos();
Videos videosFragment = new Videos();
About aboutFragment = new About();

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.navigation_home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.center, homeFragment).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_live_and_event_schedule:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.center, live_and_event_scheduleFragment).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_photos:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.center, photosFragment).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_videos:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.center, videosFragment).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_about:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.center, aboutFragment).commit();
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: @NikhilKatekhaye Thanks but I don't know how to save all fragment transaction. And don't want to go back for last fragment. Only need how to go back on web view. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override onBackPressed in the Activity. save all fragmentTransaction before addToBackStack

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //add extra code 
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know to how to save all fragment transaction. I don't want to go back for last opened fragment, I Need Back works on web view  only